# I am getting error bash: -c: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)' bash: -c: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

my script:

#!/bin/bash

ssh root@server_host '

cd /home

count=$(awk -v d1="$(date --date="now -5 minute" +"%d %b %Y %H:%M")" -v d2="$(date --date="now " +"%d %b %Y %H:%M")" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2 || $0 ~ d2' xyz.log|grep "Error Message" |wc -l)

if [ $count -gt 0 ];then
status=green
else
status=yellow
fi

timestamp=$(date --date="now - 5 minute" +"%d %b %Y %H:%M")

comment=""

if [ $status == green ];then

comment=$(awk -v d1="$(date --date="now -5 minute" +"%d %b %Y %H:%M")" -v d2="$(date --date="now " +"%d %b %Y %H:%M")" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2 || $0 ~ d2' xyz.log |grep "Error Message" |tail -1)
echo "$(hostname),$status,$timestamp,$comment"

else

comment=$(awk -v d1="$(date --date="now -5 minute" +"%d %b %Y %H:%M")" -v d2="$(date --date="now " +"%d %b %Y %H:%M")" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2 || $0 ~ d2' xyz.log | tail -1)
echo "$(hostname),$status,$timestamp,$comment"

fi

'>/csvfiles/LogsReport.csv

Answer (score 1):

SSH won't be able to execute scripts like that. What you could do is

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh root@server_host > /csvfiles/LogsReport.csv <<EOF
cd /home
...
<and the rest of your script>
EOF
```

More info on this syntax at [Here documents](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Comment: You still can't pass a complete script to SSH in quotes. You'll need to use a "Here document" as shown above, or put the lines in quotes in a separate script and execute that.

Comment: Hi,
FYI I will be executing ssh root@host ' ' from a common root server access  from where I can login to any server with username root, my script will be residing on common host only e.g my script run.sh is on host pq34 and I wanted to login to pq30 in my script and must save all the contents in  a csv on pq34 only. We can do it by doing 

run.sh:
ssh root@pq30 '
cd /home

my script content

#closing server logged in with '
'>>/csv/logsrepprt.csv
#overwriting the content in csv